# systemd-resolved switches DNS Sever

Tags: networking, server, dns, lts

I just upgraded to focal; and occasionally systemd-resolved switches from one DNS sever to another.  The issue is that I have ONE "internal" DNS server.  in my router (Netgear Orbi), I've configured that IP as both primary and secondary; but, for some reason resolved thinks that the "other" server is 8.8.8.8, which of course doesn't have my internal names.

`resolv.conf` points to 127.0.0.53 and is symlinked to `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` is empty.

Here's the output of resolvectl status:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (ens3)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.75.5
         DNS Servers: 192.168.75.5
                      8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: prosser.n7qnm.net
```

Two questions:

1. Why is it switching to the alternate server?
2. Where is it getting 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Does the router have 8.8.8.8 for its DNS lookup? If so, this could be assigned as part of the DHCP process.

Comment: It did for a while - doesn't now. I changed the routed a few days ago, and have rebooted this system since.My plan is to shift my dhcp server from the Netgear Orbi to a pihole sever I have running.  I'm hoping that will clear up some of the issues

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out.

In 20/Focal, the "Cloud Init" package comes into play, and in /etc/cloud/conf.cfg.d is a file named 50-curtin-networking.cfg that contains nameserver definitions.  The update apparently reads /etc/systemd/resolved.conf; which in my case, was populated BEFORE I added a second local DNS server; and, in 18, was not used in the same way.

"The more the tinker with the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain" - Montgomery Scott